# IPB - Hook into usercpForms_core.php

Tags: hook, signature, ipb

I'm creating a hook in Invision Power Board with a new restriction on users signature. I have to add the validation code into saveSignature() function implemented in usercpForms_core.php. Is there a way to do this? Which hook type I have to use? I've tried to use Library Hook extending usercpForms_core class, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You must create Library hook for this class. As example, it's my part of xml

```
<hook_file_real>userProfileInfo</hook_file_real>
  <hook_type>libraryHooks</hook_type>
  <hook_classname>userProfileInfo</hook_classname>
```

```
            public function saveProfileInfo()
            {
                // SOME CODE

                return parent::saveProfileInfo();
            }   
      }]]></hooks_source>
```